# Should I rename image files for faster access/less memory?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have around 3000 jpegs that I'm using in my app. The image names and a brief description are stored in a SQL database that is read into the momd. One image appears on the screen at at time.

The images have a wide variety of names, some directly from the camera, DSC1014 and others that are quire long, e.g. A5_09-DOUBLE-DECKER-BRIDGE and 2012-05-13_19-06-22_790.

I haven't noticed any issues with memory or access times on my iPod or iPad but wondered if it help with memory or access times to give the pictures short names e.g img001, etc.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that shortening names will improve performance?

Comment: Take some time to read about **Instruments** and use it to profile your app! Time well spent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortening the names will almost certainly not give you a noticeable advantage in terms of memory or access time. If you wish to improve access time, you should consider using indexes for your table if you are not already doing so.